# Can't fetching records from nested JSON objects in Sencha Touch Application

Tags: json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm stuck with issue for getting web-service response from **JSON** in **Sencha Touch**.

I'm getting response from server.

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
   {
       "type": "Feature",
       "id": "business_poi_en.1",
       "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
               28.21962354993591,
               36.452844361147314
          ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
       "status": "M",
       "score": 100,
       "side": "R",
       "ref_id": 0,
       "id": null,
       "business_p": "AQUARIOUM",
    }
},
{
   "type": "Feature",
   "id": "business_poi_en.2",
   "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
         28.225417523605692,
         36.436470953176716
      ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
       "status": "M",
       "score": 68.44,
       "match_type": "A",
       "side": "L",
       "ref_id": 0,
       "id": null,
       "business_p": "ZIGOS",
    }
},

.... So On ....
```

I want to fetch data for **coordinates** from **geometry** tag, so I can display it on map via these coordinates.
I also want to fetch data for **business_p** from **properties** tag as displaying title on map.

But, I can't get both of values for coordinates & business_p at same time from same response.

Any idea for getting values at same time ?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Please help with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post store and model as well ?

Comment: your json objects should be in an array

Answer (score 0):

Your Store's proxy's reader should have correct `rootProperty` which is common parent of both `coordinates` and `business_p`. For that your response should be wrapped into a top level tag like this

```
{
  "featureResponse": [
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "features": []
    },
  ]
}
```

Then you can define reader like this:

```
reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'featureResponse'
        }
```

once you get record from this store, you can go to `data` or `raw` children object to fetch required data.